# Hotkeys set to open apps in windows 10

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I set a hotkey in windows 10 to open Adobe Acrobat 15 which was recently removed and replaced with newer version Acrobat 17.  I then set the same hotkey CTRL-ALT A to Acrobat 17, but I get an error message when I try to use it because the hotkey is looking for Acrobat 15 which it cannot find. How do I remove the hotkey looking for Adobe 15 and reset it to look for and open 
Acrobat 17?